# How to use AppleScript to run any app as root?

Tags: macos, applescript

I write some AppleScript to run "Turbo Boost Switcher" as admin and save it as appication so i can launch it with root access without typing password. also add my moded script it into login item

I can use “Open at login” option in Turbo Boost Switcher but it ask my password Every time when startup and it is irritating. my goal is how I get a pro feature for free!? The features is No password prompt every time when open at login and my attempt is using AppleScript to run this app as root so it won’t ask my password again. Saving few seconds!

. Every time when my saved AppleScript app open, It run successful. But the script app itself say "not responding" after run. So I need to manually quit it.

Here is my script (My saved script as app is "TurboAdmin"

```
do shell script ¬
    "/Applications/Turbo\\ Boost\\ Switcher.app/Contents/MacOS/Turbo\\ Boost\\ Switcher" user name "CLASSIFIED" password "CLASSIFIED" with administrator privileges
tell application "TurboAdmin"
    quit
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke return
    end tell
end tell
```

Using this script give a root access but the script never stop and take a lot of my battery so I need to force quit

using this command will not give “not responding” . but won’t give a root access CR: wch1zpink

```
  tell application "Turbo Boost Switcher.app” to activate
```

Comment: Is there some reason you just can't use the **Open at Login** checkbox in **Turbo Boost Switcher** settings from its menu bar icon?

Comment: The script won't end until the process the shellscript launched ends.

Comment: I'm cheating that app. the pro version don't need to enter password every time on startup, wake from sleep. etc and i'm experimenting with free version

Comment: I can use “Open at login” option and it ask my password and it is irritating. my question is how I get a pro feature for free!? The features is No password prompt every time when open at login and my attempt is using AppleScript to run this app as root so it won’t ask my password again. Saving few seconds!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m pretty sure that you can replace all of your code with this one line of AppleScript.  With this, you will not need to worry about having to quit "TurboAdmin.app”

```
tell application "Turbo Boost Switcher.app” to activate
```

Comment: the command run successful. but not admin!!!

Answer (score 2):

After a hours of derps! I run this app as admin without password window.

```
do shell script "/Applications/Turbo\\ Boost\\ Switcher.app/Contents/MacOS/Turbo\\ Boost\\ Switcher >/dev/null 2>&1 &" user name "CLASSIFIED" password "CLASSIFIED" with administrator privileges
```

I made a Self-quiting script